# Xamarin *.aar Android Java Binding Google Cardboard VR showing only Java.Interop

Tags: android, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android, aar

I recently started using Xamarin, and currently I'm trying to build a simple Android application using Google Cardboard. More specifically, I've been trying to use the [VrPanoramaView](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/vrview) within Xamarin.

I've tried binding the [libraries](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/tree/master/libraries) provided in Java by using the Binding Library projects and having each of the *.aar files' **Build Action** set to **LibraryProjectZip**.

Nevertheless, whenever I add the generated *.dll as a refence to a project and view it in the Object Browser the classes don't show up. What I end up with when I expand the refence:

**LibraryBindingRefence**

- Com.Google.VR.Audio
- Com.Google.VR.Sdk.Audio
- Java.Interop

Hence, whenever I try to add the widget within an .axml file I get the following message:

```
<com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
  android:id="@+id/pano_view"
  android:layout_margin="5dip"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:scrollbars="@null"
  android:layout_height="250dip" />
```

> "The 'com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView' is not declared."

Comment: You might be better off just using Xamarin's https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/d24d35b962c910edbeed3e338ae2f405d36041b5/XPlat/GoogleVR/Android/source/Google.VR.Android I did not look at which version of Google's VR it is using but that will show you a complete binding setup along with the needed java transforms and additions (there are a few classes/methods that need to be implemented in C#)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution here? Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't get it to work and switched to native instead.

Comment: I think this will take a Xamarin binding expert to fix. I got over the first hurdle by adding <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.google.vr.sdk.base']/class[@name='Eye.Type']" name="name">EyeType</attr> to the Metadata.xml transform ('Type' is a clash-to-far for the binder). However, I still have 43 warnings related to failed bindings that I can't resolve.